# Getting NoSuchFileException: while starting Kafka instance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use Apache Kafka Connect to consume tweets from Twitter and get them into my Kafka instance. I met a strange problem, namely, I am running a script:

```
connect-standalone.bat connect-standalone.properties twitter.properties
```

and I am receiving a list of errors in console log like:

```
[2019-10-07 11:48:02,758] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter)
[2019-10-07 11:48:12,759] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Flush of offsets threw an unexpected exception:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSourceTask.java:472)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.commit(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:111)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.access$000(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter$1.run(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:231)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:219)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:92)
        ... 6 more
[2019-10-07 11:48:12,763] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter)
[2019-10-07 11:48:22,765] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Flush of offsets threw an unexpected exception:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSourceTask.java:472)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.commit(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:111)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.access$000(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter$1.run(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:231)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:219)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:92)
        ... 6 more
[2019-10-07 11:48:22,770] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter)
[2019-10-07 11:48:32,772] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Flush of offsets threw an unexpected exception:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSourceTask.java:472)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.commit(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:111)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.access$000(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter$1.run(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore$2.call(MemoryOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:231)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:219)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore.save(FileOffsetBackingStore.java:92)
        ... 6 more
[2019-10-07 11:48:32,776] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=TwitterSourceDemo-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter)
```

Seemingly this should not work but my Kafka-Consumer which is listening to Kafka-Cluster is receiving tweets despite these errors which occurs while Kafka start.

My connect-standalone.properties looks like:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=connectors
```

twitter.properties looks like:

```
name=TwitterSourceDemo
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.twitter.TwitterSourceConnector

twitter.oauth.accessTokenSecret=accesTokenSecret
process.deletes=false
filter.keywords=bitcoin
kafka.status.topic=twitter_status_connect
kafka.delete.topic=twitter_deletes_connect
twitter.oauth.consumerSecret=consumerSecret
twitter.oauth.accessToken=accessToken
twitter.oauth.consumerKey=consumerKey
```

Visual tree of my project:

[image]

I'm looking for a problem in the line:

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

because I am using Windows 10 which doesn't have this path.

I want to know if it is possible to fix my configuration to rid off these errors while Kafka start.

I will be grateful for a suggestion how to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the configuration from `offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets` to e.g. `offset.storage.file.filename=\kafka\test\connect.offsets` (make sure to create `\kafka\test\` )

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I should create your suggested directory in the kafka-connect directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Windows 10 which doesn't have this path.

Then change it to a path that does exist?

```
file://c:/Users/your_name/kafka_connect.offsets
```

Alternatively, run `connect-distributed.bat`, which doesn't use files for offsets and stores that data back into a Kafka topic.

---

Note: Kafka itself should be reporting a similar error because the default `logs.dir` is under `/tmp` as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was confused because these are my first steps with Kafka on Windows and I was not sure where I suppose to store offsets. Can You suggest a silver bullet configuration for a launched Kafka on windows to store offsets properly?

Comment: I would suggest using connect-distributed, as mentioned. Then it should run on any system without relying on file paths

Answer (score 0):

After searching for an hour, I found a solution.

One Solution is Running `connect-distributed.bat`

---

But if you want to use `connect-standalone.bat`, Just create a new folder (`tmp`) in your Kafka folder.

and then change the value mentioned below in `connect-standalone.properties`.

```
offset.storage.file.filename=C:/kafka/tmp/connect.offsets
```

After that, Restart Zookeeper and Kafka and run Kafka-connect again. now there will be no errors. It will automatically create a new file name in the tmp folder called `connect.offsets`